# Understanding latency in GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer

Just want to confirm that my understanding of latency is correct.

Each element that introduces latency (audio capture, video capture, jitter buffer, etc.) reports a min latency value, which is the minimum downstream elements must wait in order to synchronize playback.

Each element looks upstream, and sets its latency value to the `MAX(min latencies)`

For example:

```
    element 1                   element 2                element 3             element 4             element 5
[ min latency 200 ] -> [ no latency introduced]  -> [ min latency 500 ] -> [ min latency 200 ] -> [ sink element ]
```

- element 1 latency = 200 ms
- element 2 latency = 200 ms
- element 3 latency = (upstream min + own min) = 200 ms + 500 ms = 700 ms
- element 4 latency = (upstream min + own min) = 700 ms + 200 ms = 900 ms
- element 5 latency = 900 ms (total latency the pipeline will delay playback by)

`MAX(200, 200, 700, 900) = 900 = pipeline latency value`

Is this correct?